# call function from controller - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to call a simple function in angularjs, but when im calling the function from the controller,
the app crash. for example, if i call the function from ng-click event, everything is working fine.

the code is about json object array that i want to push his data to another array

the code:

```
$scope.imgindex=[];


$scope.makeindex = function()
{
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.zimmers.length;i++)
  {
    $scope.imgindex.push({id:$scope.zimmers[i]['ZimmerID'],index:0});
  }
}


makeindex();
```

Comment: use `$scope.makeindex();`

Comment: i tried, when im doing it the app crush

Comment: Can you post the error from browser console.

Comment: no error, only the app stop working

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this question is very broad as it is written. Please take a read through [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the object `$scope.zimmers` to give you a clear answer, but apparently your code has an error when you trying to access the `$scope.zimmers[i]['ZimmerID']` variable, maybe you are trying access before it is available.